# Rails remove has_one without save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

How can I remove a `has_one` relationship with committing to the database?

```
class Foo
  has_one :bar

  validates :bar, presence: true
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo

  validates :foo, presence: true
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.build_bar
foo.save # => success

foo.bar = nil # => Failed to remove the existing associated bar. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.
```

I've been searching for a while online and am not finding a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can no assign `bar` as `nil` as it need a foreign key

try:

```
foo.bar.destroy
```